# Generating covariates from Bernoulli Distribution with a particular correlation structure in R

Tags: r

I am trying to reproduce a simulation result from an article using R and I am stuck at the very beginning. I am supposed to generate say some 10 covariates, all follow bernoulli distribution, where they are correlated by the regression structure: `p(X_j=1|X_j-1)=0.1+0.1(X_j-1 - 0.15), j=1,...,10`, for `n=100` individuals, and `X1~Binomial(1,0.5)`. I thought it's supposed to be easy but I think I am missing something and have no idea how to proceed. Any suggestion or idea (even clearing me out what they are trying to say) would be really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Recursive definitions like these are messy. You can use a loop

```
draw <- function() {
    N<-10
    x <- numeric(N)
    x[1] <- runif(1) < .5
    for(i in 2:N) {
        x[i] <- runif(1) < 0.1+0.1*(x[i] - 0.15)
    }
}
draw()
```

or a Reduce function

```
Reduce(function(xjm1,x) {
    as.numeric(runif(1) < .1+.1*(xjm1-0.15)) }, 
    rep(0,9), init=runif(1)>.5, accumulate=T)
```

If you needed to generate a bunch of these values and calculate the correlation, you could do

```
xx <- replicate(100, draw())
cor(t(xx))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I made a small correction in the question. I didn't understand your logic. Perhaps, my incomplete question was the reason for your answer. My correlation matrix for this 10 covariates will be a 10x10 matrix and later, I need to generate a data for 100 individuals for this 10 covariates (100x10 matrix) considering this correlation structure. I know I can use 'bindata' package to generate the data, but I am unsure how to form the correlation matrix considering the correlation structure.

Comment: Do you want to calculate an empirical correlation matrix from a random sample with this distribution or the analytical/theoretical correlation? If the latter, that's a statistical problem, not a programming one and would be better asked at [stats.se]. If the former, I've updated my response.

Comment: I want to calculate the empirical correlation matrix following the regression structure for 10 covariates and then generate the covariates for 100 individual where the covariates are correlated by the correlation structure. BTW, I want to generate them from a binomial distribution not uniform. Again, thank you so much for your helpful replies.